# Обработка ожидающих событий QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Tags: qt, qt4

Есть объект класса, в котором определены два слота. В слоте А в цикле выполняется длительная по времени операция. При завершении каждой итерации цикла вызываю метод `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` для обработки накопившихся событий.

Вопрос следующий: если за время выполнения длительной операции какой-то другой объект вызовет сигнал, подключенный к слоту В моего объекта, то выполнится ли слот В до завершения выполнения слота А?
Использую Qt версии 4.8, всё выполняется в одном потоке.

примерный код:

```
void MyObject::slotA(int sz)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    /*Здесь длительная операция*/
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
  }
}

void MyObject::slotB()
{
  /*Здесь ещё какой-то код*/
}
```

Хочу чтоб была следующая последовательность вызовов:

```
slotA():
длительная операция #1
processEvents()
длительная операция #2
processEvents()
...
длительная операция #n
processEvents()
slotB() // когда событие ожидает вызова
длительная операция #n+1
processEvents()
...
завершение выполнения slotA()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнится, так как контекст выполнения при заходе в `processEvents()` в цикле будет обрабатывать каждое отложенное на текущий момент событие с доставкой последнего адресату и выполнению сразу же на месте в соответствующем обработчике событий, будь то `QObject::event()` или `QObject::customEvent()` для событий пользовательского уровня.

После выполнения всех имеющихся на текущий момент событий, в том числе и после захода в `slotB()`, контекст выполнения вернётся в цикл слота `slotA()`.

Разумеется, что если итерация в цикле слота `slotA()` довольно длительна, то неисключены притормаживания как интерфейса пользователя, так и любых других псевдопараллельных задач. Приходится, либо устанавливать для `processEvents()` вторым аргументом время ожидания для подхода новых событий, либо просто увеличивать количество вызовов `processEvents()`, располагая их в разных местах в теле цикла. И хотя это ведёт к меньшему количеству обозначенных выше притормаживаний, но в тоже самое время увеличивает длительность выполнения самого слота `slotA()` в целом. Здесь уже нужно исходить из задачи, определяясь с тем, какой из подзадач отдать больший приоритет.

Могу также порекомендовать обратиться к `QStateMachine`. Несмотря на то, что многие считают данный инструмент избыточным для решения простых задач, тем не менее он прекрасно отрабатывает в ситуациях, когда требуется асинхронность. Профит от его использования проявляется также и в том, что, лишь однажды составив цепочку состояний, далее уже можно не беспокоиться о подобного рода проблемах на вроде притормаживаний пользовательского интерфейса при выполнении асинхронных задач.

Если же для слота `slotA()` важна максимальная скорость выполнения, но при этом другие задачи не должны останавливаться, то альтернативы многопоточности нет.

Comment: А если некий объект за время длительной итерации цикла вызвал `slotB`, допустим, 5 раз, то `slotB` во время выполнения `processEvents()` будет вызван те же 5 раз подряд?

Comment: Да. Некий объект, вызывая слот `slotB()` через очередь событий (а иначе асинхронная работа попросту невозможна), при каждом таком вызове создаёт тем самым объект `QEvent`, который и ставится в очередь. Осуществить это возможно, например, через `QMetaObject::invoke()` с флагом `Qt::QueuedConnection`.